# custom checkbox repeating in ie7 and ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Custom check box of a form I am buidling seems to get repeated in IE7. I am using "custom-form-elements.js" from http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

It is working fine except the check box seems like repeating in IE7 and IE8. I have added the javascript file as stated there. Attached is my check box image file[image: CHECKBOX IMAGE]

In the javascript file I have changed the width/height as below

```
var checkboxHeight = "24";
```

And in my css as below

```
.checkbox {
    width: 25px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    background: url(../images/checkbox.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the CSS from bootstrap.min.css overrides your CSS for the padding of the element. Bootstrap.min.css has a rule:

```
 .form-horizontal .checkbox {
     padding-top: 7px;
     ...
 }
```

This overrides your padding rule, so in effect the element has a 7px top padding. This increases the element's height on IE7 and you see the background image that extends downwards.

A fix could be making your CSS rule more specific, for example `.form-horizontal .ticks .checkbox {...}` or adding an `!important` for your padding.